# If a container is in a vacuum state, what will inside the container?

Tags: vacuum

Let say I can make the container or a bottle vacuum inside, what will actually inside? If this is not vacuum, we can say that it is fill with air, but if we make it vacuum... Will the bottle or container, reduce their size? Thanks.

Comment: You accidentally a verb...did you mean "what will *be* inside the container"?

Comment: "Perfect Vacuum" only exists in equations it is theoretically implausible in real world applications. You will always have something inside.

Answer (score 6):

In reality the small fraction of the air you hadn't managed to remove.
Even if you could make a perfect vacuum pump (you can't) then there would be molecules from the material making up the walls of the container which will boil off into the vacuum.

Ignoring engineering details and with a perfect vacuum there would still be a sea of infrared photons emitted from the walls and of course there is an ever present stream of neutrinos from the sun and space sources which are constantly streaming through everything.

But even if you had a perfect vacuum, at absolute zero, in space, an infinite distance from any stars (!) there would be quantum effects which caused virtual particle pairs to be created out of nothing

Comment: +1 a complete answer, including answers to any possible "what if" comments.

Comment: You ask "Will the bottle or container, reduce their size?". Yes it will because the atmospheric pressure will exert a crushing force on the bottle, though how much it shrinks it depends how strong the bottle is. For a typical glass bottle the shrinkage is too small to measure easily. For a plastic pop bottle the bottle would probably collapse. I've just tried sucking the air out of a 2L plastic lemonade bottle (takes strong lungs :-) and it did collapse.